# PHP How to remove last part of a path

Tags: php

I have a path like this:

`parent/child/reply`

How do I use PHP to remove the last part of the path, so that it looks like this:

`parent/child`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
dirname($path)
```

[And this is the documentation.](https://www.php.net/dirname)

Answer (score 28):

[`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php). You can use it as many times as you'd like

- to get parent/child - dirname('parent/child/reply')
- to get parent - dirname(dirname('parent/child/reply'))

Answer (score 7):

[`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
    preg_replace("/\/\w+$/i","",__DIR__);
     # Note you may also need to add .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR at the end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here' is a function to remove the last **n** part of a URL:

```
/**
 * remove the last `$level` of directories from a path
 * example 'aaa/bbb/ccc' remove 2 levels will return aaa/
 *
 * @param $path
 * @param $level
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function removeLastDir($path, $level)
{
    if (is_int($level) && $level > 0) {
        $path = preg_replace('#\/[^/]*$#', '', $path);

        return $this->removeLastDir($path, (int)$level - 1);
    }

    return $path;
}
```

Comment: Really? Regular expressions and recursion? Why not a `for` loop with `dirname`? To simple?

Answer (score 2):

More simple, if you have a path like

```
$path="/p1/p2/.../pN"
```

you can use 'dirname()' function as

```
echo dirname($path,L)
```

where 'L' is the level to up. For L=1, is the current folder, L=2 is the '../pN-1', for L=3 we have "../pN-2" e so on ...

For sample, is your path is `'$path="/etc/php/7.4/apache2/"'`, and L=2, so

```
echo dirname($path,2)
```

will output

```
/etc/php/7.4/
```

for L=3

```
/etc/php
```

Thats it.