# Removing part of path in php

Tags: php, path, directory

I have a path like:

```
$path='somefolder/foo/bar/lastdir';
```

and I want to remove the last part, so I have:

```
$path='somefolder/foo/bar';
```

Like I went one folder up.

I'm really newbie in php, maybe its just one function, although I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: As a very quick and dirty fix.... You could always just trying catting `../` onto the end of your existing path.

Comment: Well, I would deafinitely prefer to remove the last folder than to do this. If nothing else works, I will try this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How to remove last part of a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430208/php-how-to-remove-last-part-of-a-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this (tested and works as expected):

```
$path = 'somefolder/foo/haha/lastone';
$parts = explode('/', $path);
array_pop($parts);
$newpath = implode('/', $parts);
```

`$newpath` would now contain `somefolder/foo/haha`.

Answer (score 3):

use :

```
dirname(dirname('somefolder/foo/haha/lastone/somescript.php'));
```

this should return:

```
somefolder/foo/haha/
```

Comment: `dirname` has a 2nd argument `levels` so you could call it like this:

`dirname('somefolder/foo/haha/lastone/somescript.php',2);`

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but try:

```
$path_array = explode('/',$path);
array_pop($path_array);
$path = implode('/',$path_array);
```

Comment: You're missing an argument on your `implode()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently at:

```
somefolder/foo/haha/lastone/somescript.php
```

and you want to access:

```
somefolder/foo/haha/someotherscript.php
```

just type:

```
../someotherscript.php
```

Comment: see the answer below with dirname()

Answer (score 1):

Probably using a regex function would be appropriate if the last part is going to vary.  Try

```
$pattern = '#/.*$#U';
$stripped_path = preg_replace($pattern, '', $original_path);
```

This will strip everything off the original path string starting from the last forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function that explodes() the $path variable into an array and then array_pop to get rid of the last element.

```
function path($path) {
    $arrayPath = explode("/", $path);
    $path = array_pop($arrayPath);

    return $path = implode("/", $path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest variant in PHP is:

```
$path = preg_replace('|/[^/]*$|','', $path);
```

which uses a regular expression.