# how to remove the first part of a path in php?

Tags: php

i have a path like this:

```
/dude/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg
```

i want to echo it like this:

```
/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg
```

how to do this? and if you could please explain it. i found one good answer
[Removing part of path in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618318/removing-part-of-path-in-php) but i cannot work my way around with explode and implode.

**please give me the link to the duplicate answer if my question is a duplicate**

Comment: If you know which part of the path you want to remove, you could use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove root directory from a directory path string - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696977/remove-root-directory-from-a-directory-path-string-php)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$string = '/dude/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg';
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, '/', 1));
```

The `strpos` to look for the position of the `/` after the first one, then use `substr` to get the string starting from that position till the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = '/dude/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg';
$path = explode('/', $path);
unset($path[1]);
$path = implode('/', $path);
```

Will separate the string into an array, then unset the first item (technically the second in the array, since the first element will be empty due to the string starting with /). Finally the path is imploded, and you get:

```
/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$string = "/dude/stuff/lol/bruh.jpg";
$firstslash = strpos($string,"/",1);
$secondstring = substr($string, $firstslash+1);
echo "String : " . $string;
echo " <br> Result : " . $secondstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract resource name you need.

```
preg_match('/(?P<name>[^\/]+)$/', $path, $match);
```

Then you have to use `$match` as array, and you can see the name inside of it.

```
$match['name];
```