# php remove the last "/" from the path

Tags: php

this is my code

```
 $method = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

and this is my path:

```
http://localhost:8082/XXXX/controllers/User.php/newUser?name=hello
```

the result of the method is `/newUser`

I would like to have just `newUser`. IE without the `/`

could you help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$method = ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/');
```

Comment: you are the first one to asnwer, plus one, i will accept the answer when the system allows many thanks

Comment: im almost sure it was stripslashes when i first seen it. Edits are not tracked if there are no votes as far as im aware ?

Comment: @Legionar As an added precaution, you may want to consider filtering the `$_SERVER` input `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "PATH_INFO", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)`. See [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for more details...

Comment: @War10ck yes, thats true, he should do same sanitization, but OP's question was just about removing `/` from the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

use `ltrim` on the variable you want ? Seems the easiest way to me

```
$var = ltrim($var,"/");
```

Comment: plus one to your efforts, but there is a guy answered before you and it is fair to accept his/her answer, forgive me please and thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
$withoutSlash = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
```

Comment: plus one to your efforts, but there is a guy answered before you and it is fair to accept his/her answer, forgive me please and thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your question already exist:

URL: [PHP How to remove last part of a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430208/php-how-to-remove-last-part-of-a-path)

**One solution:**

```
 preg_replace("/\/\w+$/i","",__DIR__);
 # Note you may also need to add .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR at the end.
```

**Another solution:**

```
dirname($path)
Documentation: http://ca3.php.net/dirname
```

Comment: plus one to your efforts, but there is a guy answered before you and it is fair to accept his/her answer, forgive me please and thank you

Comment: Don't worry :) I'm happy with you find a solution. And thanks for the "plus one".