# How to remove filename from a url in php

Tags: php, html

I need to write a PHP function that will remove the file name inside a URL. [I don't want to simply remove the last part of a URL. Because some url's will be like http://www.examples.com/sample This "sample" cannot be a file. I only want to remove file name.

```
In. -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/index.html  
Out -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/

In. -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/
Out -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/

In. -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project
Out -> http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/
```

I think the solution is to check whether a '.' [dot] is present after the last '/'. If so, remove everything after the last '/'. But didn't get the logic to write it in PHP

I can't simply check if there exists '.html', because file name can be .php, .jpg, .jsp or anything like that

Comment: check it:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430208/php-how-to-remove-last-part-of-a-path

Comment: have you tried using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) ? or [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) ?

Comment: @roullie yes. It will fail if the url is like http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project or http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/

Comment: just use pathinfo($url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function stripFile($in){
    $pieces = explode("/", $in); // split the URL by /
    if(count($pieces) < 4) return $in . "/";
    if(strpos(end($pieces), ".") !== false){ // we got a filename at the end
        array_pop($pieces); // remove the filename
    }elseif(end($pieces) !== ""){ // it ends with a name without an extension, i.e. a directory
        $pieces[] = ""; // when $pieces is imploded, a "/" and then this "" will be appended
    }
    // else, already ends with a slash
    return implode("/", $pieces);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The perfect one!

Comment: it fails when the url is alone like www.bootstrap.com,

Comment: for echo stripFile("http://www.inforge.in");, it got output as "http:/"

Comment: Then count to ensure `count($pieces) >= 4`, else don't process. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeFile($url){
    $pieces = explode("/", $url); // split the URL by /
    if(count($pieces) < 4) return $url. "/";
    if(strpos(end($pieces), ".") !== false){ // we got a filename at the end
        array_pop($pieces); // remove the filename
    }elseif(end($pieces) !== ""){ // it ends with a name without an extension, i.e. a directory
        $pieces[] = ""; // when $pieces is imploded, a "/" and then this "" will be appended
    }
    // else, already ends with a slash
    return implode("/", $pieces);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lks = pathinfo("http://www.inforge.in/ongoingworks/main_project/index.html");
echo $lks['dirname'];
```

Comment: If i input "http://www.inforge.in/ongoingworks/main_project" then it will eliminate "main_project"